# character encoding from XML to Java

Tags: java, xml, http, encoding

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I'll put just some extract of codes, that i think are meaningful.

I'm reading some information from one xml via http request, something like this :

```
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

if i print the string **xml** to the screen i can see some problems with the codification already

then to return a document i have this

```
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

        doc = db.parse(is);
```

Although i'm fetching correctly the information from http request, i'm having problems with the enconding of the characters when i'm showing the data.

I already tried to do **is.setEncoding("UTF-8")** but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you converted the xml to a String (characters), don't do that (you most likely used the wrong encoding and corrupted the xml).  *treat xml as binary data (bytes)*.

you could use `EntityUtils.toByteArray` (okay), or you could pass the HttpEntity stream directly to the xml parser (ideal).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is not possible that the problem is with the XML rather the code?

And instead of doing EntityUtils.toString, i can use what you suggested, but then what should i put in the constructor of this object?

is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml)); //before when it was with a string
is.setCharacterStream(???); // I don't know which constructor i can use with an array of bytes.

Comment: @unpix Use [the `InputSource(InputStream)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource%28java.io.InputStream%29). If you start with a byte array, you can use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream%28byte[]%29).

Comment: Thanks, maybe it will work as well, but i already found the simplest solution

Comment: @unpix What did you find for solution ? I am also have this kind of problem.